# What the advantage of declaring variable in for

Tags: java, for-loop

I saw the following code on the Android support Library:

`for (int i = 0, z = getChildCount(); i < z; i++)`

What's the advantage to use `z = getChildCount` instead of just `i < getChildCount()` ?

Comment: It avoids repeatedly calculating `getChildCount()`. That is only of particular advantage if it is expensive to calculate.

Comment: It's also worth noting too you can have as many variables separated by a comma as desired in the initialization section, as long as they're of the same type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Declaring multiple variables inline is a questionable style, but the assignment calculates the count once at the beginning of the loop and saves the value. If the operation is expensive, it prevents spending  time computing it on each iteration.

Comment: It is also convenient when you need the Child count at hand somewhere in the for, avoiding to calculate it again. In this case, 'z' becomes more useful.

Answer (score 4):

In a for-loop, it can be broken into 3 parts:

```
for(initialization ; terminating condition ; increment){

}
```

In the for-loop, the initialization will be run only once. But the terminating condition will be checked in every iteration. Hence if you write the for loop as:

```
for (int i = 0; i<count(); i++){
}
```

count() method will run every iteration.

Writing it as below ensures `count()` will only be invoked once and the reason for that of course would be cutting down the unnecessary invoking of count().

```
for (int i = 0, z = count(); i < z; i++)
```

The above is also equivalent to writing it as (except that `z` is now outside the scope of the loop):

```
int z = count();
for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
```

Comment: It's not *equivalent* per se. `z` is now exposed to outside the for loop, which is rarely desired.